# Unable to set enviornment variable in platform builder win CE 6.0

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

Actually while building the Windows CE project getting the two errors:

> BUILD: [00:0000000015:ERRORE] C:\WINCE600\PLATFORM\ICOP_Vortex86_60CS\SRC\OAL\OALLIB\obj\x86\debug_objects.mac: create file failed.
>
> Error 3 BLDDEMO: There were errors building mytest

I think it's comes, due to unset of environment variable.

Facing problem to set environment variable `IMGRAM128` in the project properties, giving the error :

> The variable IMGRAM128 is associated with the 128 RAM catalog item.Would you like to set this variable by adding catalog item in OS design?  The varible will not be added to the environmmet tab..............

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the variable?

Do you have any other IMGRAM## variables set? Did you read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478591.aspx) and [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee479264.aspx)?